# For Loop Python not running for len

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I've written a for loop (see below) to check if one object instance has collided with any four other object instances, the function should return one if a collision has occured, to start another chain of reactions. The for loop is meant to run through four times - it only runs through once, so it's not detecting collisions with three of the receptors.

```
def spriteCollide(neurotransmitter1):
    print len(receptors)
    for i in range(len(receptors)):
        return receptors[i].receptorObjectInstance.colliderect(neurotransmitter1.neurotransmitterObjectInstance)
```

As you can see, the for loop should run through based on the length of the list containing the addresses of the four receptors objects. After a bit of running through, it will run the first time & then break the loop.

I've tried to include everything

Thanks,

Comment: You should change `for i in range(len(receptors))`...`receptors[i]`... to simply `for receptor in receptors`...`receptor`...

Comment: `for i in range(len(receptors)):`is a no-go in Python. Use `for receptor in receptors:` instead.

Answer (score 2):

The cycle exit the first time it reach the `return` statement. Store the result and then return the stored values:

```
def spriteCollide(neurotransmitter1):
    result = []
    print len(receptors)
    for i in range(len(receptors)):
        result.append(receptors[i].receptorObjectInstance.colliderect(neurotransmitter1.neurotransmitterObjectInstance)
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks, is there another way I could go about "returning" the value outside the function?

Comment: Look to the answer again.

Answer (score 2):

`return` will stop a function and return the value. If you want all the values try appending them to a list/dictionary and returning that.

```
def spriteCollide(neurotransmitter1, receptors):  # add receptors as a param
    values = []  # create an empty list to store you processed data
    print len(receptors)  # I assume this was for testing
    for i in range(len(receptors)):
        values.append(receptors[i].receptorObjectInstance.colliderect(neurotransmitter1.neurotransmitterObjectInstance))  # appends the reulst of collideDirect() to values
    return values  # returns the list so you can use it.
```

You should also think about passing `receptors` as a parameter of the function. It would easier to keep everything in the right scope and if something goes wrong because of a change to `receptors` outside the function it will be easier to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, the loop (and function) exits as soon as it hits return.  You should put your return statement under an IF condition.

For instance (assuming that colliderect() returns 1 or 0 ... or True or False) this should return 1 if any collision occurs:

```
def spriteCollide(neurotransmitter1):
    print len(receptors)
    for i in range(len(receptors)):
        if receptors[i].receptorObjectInstance.colliderect(neurotransmitter1.neurotransmitterObjectInstance):
            return 1
    return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make this better!

```
def spriteCollide(receptors,neurotransmitter):
    return any( [True if
                    receptorObjectInstance.colliderect(neurotransmitter.neurotransmitterObjectInstance)
                    else False for receptor in receptors] )
```

This builds a list of `True`s and `False`s based on whether each receptor is colliding with the neurotransmitter you pass it. It returns `True` if any of them are colliding, and `False` if none of them are.

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error for this! Not sure really where!

Comment: Probably in the indentation. I may have split those lines wrong, and iirc it matters whether it's Python2 or Python3 for splitting lines without a `\`. `def spriteCollide(receptors,neurotransmitter):` should all be on one line, and the rest should all be indented once on the next line down.

Comment: @AshleyCollinge Oops, no, it's because I forgot where the conditional goes in a list comp. Let me edit....